# Finding minimum bounding box for a set of points

Tags: python, algorithm

Im trying to find the minimum bounding box for a set of points. I used the library https://bitbucket.org/william_rusnack/minimumboundingbox/src/master/

I want to enclose these coordinates in the minimum bounding box :-

```
#INPUT COORDINATES
    ('297.153338872911', '373.3796368193535')
    ('222.75', '278.7499999999999')
    ('222.75', '278.7499999999999')
    ('42.25', '251.75')
    ('179.25', '390.5')
    ('298.403338872911', '373.3796368193535')
    ('0.6400000000000537', '240.0000000000201')
    ('75.26400000000632', '390.9120000000328')


 # OUTPUT BOUNDING BOX COORDINATES , PLOTTED 
[(-22.685403520024096, 373.8408037637353),
 (0.6400000000000432, 240.0),
 (288.84381342985046, 428.133250381587),
 (312.16921694987457, 294.2924466178517)]
```

[image]

But as you can see from the output itself
the bounding box is coming out as tilted/inclined . That's all right, but what I want is for the bounding box to be straight to the horizontal & vertical plane of my desktop. How can I achieve this **without losing the bounding box functionality** (i.e. any point popping out of the bounding box while making it straight) ?

I tried this code [also](https://github.com/dbworth/minimum-area-bounding-rectangle/blob/master/python/min_bounding_rect.py), but it rotates the rectangle and finds the best possible bounding box which mostly would be inclined rectangle. But I strictly want a straight rectangle.

Comment: Do you want to find the min and max values?

Comment: @MadPhysicist added more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sake of notation, let's assume that your points are a list of pairs (2-tuples), each pair being the `x,y` coordinates of a point.

```
point_list = [(10,12), (11,14), (15,20), ...]
```

Your orthogonal bounding box has simply x and y limits: the min and max of each coordinate:

```
x_min = min(point[0] for point in point_list)
x_max = max(point[0] for point in point_list)
y_min = min(point[1] for point in point_list)
y_max = max(point[1] for point in point_list)
```

Your bounding box is the four edges defined by those min/max values.

Comment: added more info in my question

Comment: I saw that; I don't see how the added info affects this answer.  Please explain.

Comment: I tried your code and Im getting x_min,y_min = (0.64, 240)
  & x_max,y_max = (298.4, 390.9) . How do I get bounding box from these two coordinates ? You can try looking at my input coordinates

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You now have the `x` and `y` coordinates of each corner.

Comment: but they are only two corners. Your code gives out  (xmin,ymin), (xmax,ymax) which are actually only 2 corners/coordinates.

Comment: No, my code gives all four boundaries.  *You* took only two corners from the data.  You now have the lower-left and upper-right corner points ... what are the coordinates of the other two points?  You have to make all four combinations.  BTW, I'm working in "teacher" mode here ... you're **so** close !!  :-)

Comment: From the green check mark, I gather that you figured it out.  Nice going!

Comment: thanks , it was so easy but i got stuck in complicating it :-)