# Find outer non-overlapped region coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, rectangles, bounding-box

TL; DR: Trying to find out the coordinates of the green region in O(1) time. The input is two sets of `(top_left, bottom_right)` points. So `[x_min_1, y_min_1, x_max_1, y_max_1]` and `[x_min_2, y_min_2, x_max_2, y_max_2]`. Output should be `[x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max]` for the green dotted rectangle.

Looks like an easy problem but I have been trying to find an *efficient* solution to this. I have a yellow rectangle and another orange rectangle *always* inside OR on the yellow rectangle. I would like to find the coordinates of the non-overlapping region of the yellow rectangle. Figures can explain this better.

[image: Illustration]

Constraints:

- The orange rectangle will always be inside or coincide with the yellow rectangle.
- Rectangles are always axis-parallel.

In the left figure, even though the orange rectangle is partially occluding the yellow rectangle, if we try to tightly wrap a box around the visible pixels of the yellow rectangle, we would get the box denoted by green dotted line. I want the coordinates of the green box.

In the right figure, the visible pixels of the yellow rectangle are traced by the green dotted line, which unlike the left figure, do not cover the entire yellow rectangle.

I wanted the coordinates of the green box as the output. Is there an O(1) solution to this?

Easy and computationally expensive solution would be to do `np.where` on yellow pixels and find the coordinates of the green box by taking min and max of the `np.where` output.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63273388/

Comment: I am not sure how a minimum bounding box around a set of points is going to help. I think that would require me to trace the path of the visible yellow rectangle border pixels, not sure how to do that efficiently and elegantly.

Comment: So all you have is a two color image that obeys the stated rules? no coordinates within the image?

Comment: How about examining all points only at the outer edges of the image and inferring the location and size of the orange rectangle from the locations of the transitions between the two colors?

Comment: The colors are only for illustration, there are no colors in the input. The input is two sets of (top_left, bottom_right) points. So `[x_min_1, y_min_1, x_max_1, y_max_1]`  and `[x_min_2, y_min_2, x_max_2, y_max_2]` .

Comment: *"Looks like an easy problem but I have been trying to find an efficient solution to this."*  If you have a working but inefficient solution, include it in the question.  It will help clarify what you are doing, and will allow proposed solutions to be tested against it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, the only the time the green box does not coincide with the entire yellow rectangle is when the orange rectangle occupies an entire edge, i.e. when two of its adjacent corners are the same as the yellow rectangle. So you really only need to compare the corners of each rectangle. There are three general cases:

1. Zero or one of the corners are the same: green is the entire yellow rectangle
2. All of the corners are the same: ??? (not sure what you want to do when they completely overlap)
3. Two adjacent corners are the same: the interesting case

In case (3) the green rectangle is composed of the four non-equal corners: two of yellow's and two of orange's.